# Class or href attribute first?

Tags: html, anchor

When using an anchor tag, is it best practice to put the class first or the href?

```
<a class="this-class" href="#">Home</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="#" class="this-class">Home</a>
```

Comment: It absolutely 100% does not matter. Do what you prefer, or pick randomly every time like I do.

Comment: Doesn't matter, but for practical purposes, I recommend you to always put `class` as the first attribute for every element. It will keep your code organized and easier to work with css association.

Comment: Doesn't matter but be consistent. I prefer the latter because it's an attribute that defines the purpose and design of the element. #id, [name], and .class in that order from specific to general is my preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is irrelevant, but it is good practice to pick an order (i.e. href then class) and keep it consistent throughout your application.